# -Wunused-but-set-variable is emitted when I use 'auto' and not when I use the corresponding type instead of 'auto'

Tags: c++, compiler-warnings, auto

Please consider the following:

```cpp
#include <functional>

int main() {
    std::function<int(int)> f_sq = [](int i) -> int { return i *= i; }; // No warning
    auto f_sub = [](int a, int b) -> int { return a - b; };             // -Wunused-but-set-variable

    return 0;
}
```

Why compiler warns when the `auto` keyword is used, and/or, in the contrary, why it doesn't when `auto` is not used?

---

- `clang version 12.0.1`
- `gcc (GCC) 11.1.0`
- `Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (artixlinux)`

Comment: The linked target is identical apart from the fact that you've used a lambda, instead of an `int`/`double`, so I think it's sufficiently close to be marked as a duplicate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`std::function<int(int)>` has a non [trivial destructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/destructor#Trivial_destructor), so might be a RAII object.

Your lambda (remember, lambda is NOT a `std::function`) has trivial destructor, so it is not a RAII object, so it is really unused.

You might minimize your example with simpler types to avoid confusion lambda/`std::function`:

```
std::vector<int> v = {4, 8, 15, 16, 23, 42}; // No warnings
int n = 42;                                  // -Wunused-but-set-variable
```

Comment: Oh dear, I don't know what (non)trivial constructor is. I need to study them.

Comment: trivial destructor (typo, not constructor :) )link added. Basically, trivial destructor is known to be noop (by compiler).

Comment: So, I have two questions. 1. Why compiler does not warn for an unused RAII object? 2. What does it mean for a lambda function to have a destructor?

Comment: As RAII object might have a scope meaning: you don't want warning for [`std::lock_guard`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock_guard). The real usage is just to define the variable and not use afterward.

Comment: (non-capture) `lambda` has trivial destructor, std::function is a type-erasure type, which has a provided destructor (to "deallocate" the erased type).